# Drag iOS Web App (Adobe Edge Animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, jquery-ui

I´m on a  big problem with this project. This is an HTML5 interactive Book for Tablets I´m using Edge Animate and my problem is with the drag and drop. On the browsers I can drag the image I want but on iOS I try everything but nothing changes. I explain my steps.

1- Get drag works on the browsers with JQuery making my objet .draggable.

2- I use the the mousedown to make it draggable and mouse out to destroy it. This is because I´m moving a light and this is the way I could make it works.

3- I set this function
            document.ontouchmove = function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

to stop the scrolling of the app on iOS.

3- I copy the code from the mouse down/up to touch start/end (I also have the mouses events for my browser Checkings)

4- Now the scrolling it´s ok  and I can tap all my action triggers but my draggable image does not move.

Please I need some help I´m out of ideas and I couldn´t find an answer

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to implement additional library - jQuery UI Touch Punch.

I was using once draggable, but I've decided to make my own "draggable". If you want to make something a bit complicated then it's the only way to go. If make your custom solution, you can give up that addition library and get a bit better performance.

Btw, there are also some graphic artifacts (blinking) when you use jquery draggable on ipad - at least I had that kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks I´m gonna deal with it and the tell you if it´s works. The truth is that Edge Animate works quickly with the animation and simple codes  for browser but I´m not really happy about how it use the code and implementations...

Comment: Why are you unhappy about edge animate's workflow and implementations? In this case it's more about only jquery library.